# mvc view shows only the json not HTML

Tags: html, json, asp.net-core-mvc

i'm trying to get started with MVC (using .net core). 
Here is the controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Contacts()
    {
        //THIS RENDERS THE VIEW AS HTML
        //return View(Mapper.Map<List<WebContacts.Business.Contact>, List<ContactsViewModel>>(WebContacts.Business.Contact.GetContacts().ToList()));

        // THIS DISPLAYS THE RETURNED JSON Object 
        return Ok(Mapper.Map<List<WebContacts.Business.Contact>, List<ContactsViewModel>>(WebContacts.Business.Contact.GetContacts().ToList()));
    }
```

In the controller if I return View(); it renders the razor partial view as expected (html etc), if i use
Return OK() i just get the JSON[image: ![JSON instead of the rendered view]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqsAj.png)

Thanks for any help.
ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return OK(object) sends a HTTP response to the client containing the object. return View(object) passes processing over to the view engine which returns HTML to the client. What problem are you trying to resolve?

Comment: I want the view to render the Ok(object) as HTML.

Comment: or is nothing actually wrong, I just need to bring something like Angular...?

Comment: You should use View, Ok is for Web APIs